# What's the penalty for filing taxes late in canada if you're owed a refund?

Tags: taxes, income-tax, canada

For a number of totally avoidable reasons, I just filed my taxes. I'm owed ~3500$ and I was wondering what I should expect to get from the CRA. I've heard there's no penalty for filing late unless you owe the CRA money. Is this true? I couldn't find anything about it on the CRA's website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's true for the tax return.  The T1135 has some late penalties.  These only apply if you had to file one, some/most people don't.

http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/tx/nnrsdnts/cmmn/frgn/pnlts_grd-eng.html